# basic mod_perl question

Tags: apache, mod-perl

I am very newbie to Perl.

I wrote a very simple Perl program (script):

```
print "hello";
```

When I execute it on command prompt (with command - perl first.pl), it works.

However, when I use the same Perl code in "filter" of apache it doesn't work. To provide more details, I am invoking a filter for a URL in Apache Http Server with following configuration in httpd.conf file:

```
<Location /something.do>
      SetHandler modperl
      PerlResponseHandler MyApache2::FirstPerlProg
</Location>
```

FirstPerlProg.pm file (in indigoampp\perl-5.12.1\site\lib\MyApache2 location) has same code as first.pl.

The index.html page (first page) has a form which submits request to something.do and this filter gets invoked.

The issue is, how and where do I see this filter's output (hello)?

Hope my question is clear.

I know that I am not making any HTTP response to be sent to browser in this filter code and that's why I get 'page can't be displayed' after submit. However what shall I do is something I don't know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you wrote it.  Going by your code, the skeleton should look like

```
package MyApache2::FirstPerlProg;

use Apache2::Const qw(OK);
use Apache2::RequestRec;
use Apache2::RequestIO;

sub handler {
  my ($r) = @_;
  $r->content_type("text/html");
  $r->print("hello");
  return OK;
}

1;
```

This would be roughly the bare minimum for a mod_perl request handler.  And this should be the response coming back from the request, should see it in the browser.  You can also use `Apache2::Log` and then use `$r->log_error("text")` to send to the error_log.

If you want your script to run CGI-ish, then use the ModPerl::Registry.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I kind of figured out this but the thing is I want to invoke "servlet" as well for "something.do" URL pattern which is deployed on WebLogic Application Server.

Comment: When I use PerlResponseHandler it doesn't invoke "actual" resource requested, instead it creates response itself. I just want to modify request in filter and let requested resource to handle response generation part...

Comment: If I use other filter say (PerlInputFilterHandler), the page just hangs - it calls itself again and again - and never gets to servlet...

Comment: See your other posted question for the answer to the PerlInputFilterHandler question i answered.